# Replacing Multimeters with Megaohmmeters

Tags: resistance, measurement, electrical

Standard Digital multimeters can measure up to the ranges of 20 Megaohms. Then why should we use Meggers at all?

Comment: What makes you think that 20 MΩ is the largest resistance you can encounter?

Comment: 20 Megaohm is definitely not the largest resistance one can encounter . What I wanted to know was if we can use multimeters instead of meggers while measuring a resistance of that order .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordinary multimeter uses low voltage to measure the resistance. A megger has a high voltage power supply for measuring, indeed the measured resistance is different compared to multimeter, when you test the broken insulation. The multimeter will show infinity, but as soon you use a megger with specified test voltage you find out that the resistance is very low - insulation breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia...

> Megohmmeter (sometimes referred to as a megger) is a special type of ohmmeter used to measure the electrical resistance of insulators. Insulating components, for example cable jackets, must be tested for their insulation strength at the time of commissioning and as part of maintenance of high voltage electrical equipment and installations. For this purpose megohmmeters, which can provide high DC voltages (typically in ranges from 500 V to 2 kV) at specified current capacity, are used. Acceptable insulator resistance values are typically 1 to 10 megohms, depending on the standards referenced.

Meggers will measure into the GΩ and TΩ ranges.

Don't try using one on your logic circuit though...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of components that show high resistance at low voltages but then suffer breakdown when subjected to higher voltages (ziener diode and low voltage capacitors being the obvious examples).

Meggers with their higher test voltage in the 1kV-2kV range are used to ensure the high resistance is still apparent in a high voltage situation.