# Megger terminals clarification

Tags: resistance, testing, insulation

I saw that some meggers inject the test voltage / current from the - (minus) terminal while do this from the + (plus) terminals (don't know why, it probably depends on the manufacturer?)
Currently I come around a new Metrel MI 3200 type which I am sure that the injection is made from the + (plus) terminal, but I do don't find any reference for this. Can someone enlighten me?
Also I would like to know what will hapen if you accidentaly connect vice versa the megger (plus instead of minus or viceversa depending the equipment) to let's say a power transformer 20/0,4 kV, so basically injectiong a medium voltage into the seconday side, in this case of low voltage (400V) type ? You will damage the low voltage side, right?
So basically, when performing insulation resistance on equipment, does it matter which lead on a megger goes where? If I'm testing insulation resistance from A to B, does it matter if the Red lead goes on A or B?

Please note that I am a beginer in this domain and I am not performing any megger measurements myself.

[image]

Comment: For anyone who wonders (like me once), what a "Megger" is: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/296328/64158

Comment: All cuurent flows from negative terminal to positive terminal (electron flow), so you will have to clarify what you mean by *I am sure that the injection is made from the + (plus) terminal*.  A meggar generates a high voltage and measures the resultant current to determine if the insulation resistance is breaking down.  You clearly have access to instruction manual.  What other meggar has led you to your conclusion?